# Replacing component in panel without it going to the end?

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel

I am working on a program that has no errors when I compile, and the logic runs soundly for it's purpose (I'm making a basic Penny Pitch program in GUI). The board is filled with image icons that contain the number of points a player will receive if they land on it, and when they land on a spot the image icon is suppose to switch to a picture of the same spot with a penny on it. However, when the previous icon is removed and the new "occupied" one is assigned, it is assigned at the end of the panel rather than the previous spot the "empty" icon was taken from.

To illustrate:
this is the normal layout,
[before "tossing" a penny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow27c.png),
and this is the shifted layout,
[after "tossing" a penny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dDpR.png).

I can't find any sources explaining how to add a component to a panel in a spot previously occupied by a removed component. If anyone knows how, it would be great help!

-----------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------

New pictures:[image: before the toss],[image: after the toss].

I'm using a GridBagLayout now, and since I'm still not sure what is the cause of the new added component not taking the space of the removed one, I cut down my entire program to illustrate it's aspects:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PennyPitch extends JFrame implements ItemListener{

    //variables
    int aa=0, thrown=0, place=0, illit=1, illit2=1;
    Random pitch = new Random();
    private ImageIcon full = new ImageIcon("pitchFull.png");
    //map
    private Map tossing;
    //jbuttons            
    private JButton confirm = new JButton (new ImageIcon("pitchPenny.png"));  
    //map
    private Map<Integer, ColorPanel> spot = new HashMap<Integer, ColorPanel>();
    //declared icon to use when button is pushed
    private ColorPanel rSet = new ColorPanel(Color.white, full);
    //panel
    private JPanel input = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout ());
    private GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
public PennyPitch(){
    prepareGUI();
    }
public static void main(String[] args){
  PennyPitch pitch = new PennyPitch();      }

private void prepareGUI(){
   //background
    input.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    //button design
    confirm.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    confirm.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    //icon for use
    ImageIcon one = new ImageIcon("pitchOne.png");
//components for map
    ColorPanel i1 = new ColorPanel(Color.white, one);
    ColorPanel i2 = new ColorPanel(Color.white, one);
    ColorPanel i3 = new ColorPanel(Color.white, one);   

//MAP FOR THE STATS
    spot.put(1, i1);
    spot.put(2, i2);
    spot.put(3, i3);
//PANEL
            c.ipady = 50;
            c.ipadx = 50;
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridwidth = 1;
        input.add(spot.get(1),c);
            c.ipady = 50;
            c.ipadx = 50;
            c.gridx = 2;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridwidth = 1;
        input.add(spot.get(2),c);
            c.ipady = 50;
            c.ipadx = 50;
            c.gridx = 3;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridwidth = 1;
        input.add(spot.get(3),c);
            c.ipady = 50;
            c.ipadx = 50;
            c.gridx = 4;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridwidth = 2; 
        input.add(confirm,c);

//listener for button        
confirm.addActionListener (new AddListener());

//CONTAINER
Container container = getContentPane();
container.add(input);

//frame information 
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    setSize(600, 600);
    setTitle("PENNY PITCH");
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack ();
    setVisible(true);
}
private class AddListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
    if (a.getSource()== confirm) {
                //generates number to land on
                thrown = pitch.nextInt(3) + 1;
                System.out.println(thrown);

            place=illit;
            spot.put(place, rSet);
            Component old = input.getComponent(thrown);
            Component newn = input.getComponent(place);
            Component[] compSet=input.getComponents();
                for(int i=0; i<compSet.length; i++){
                    if(old.equals(compSet[i])) {
                        input.remove(old);
                            c.ipady = 50;
                            c.ipadx = 50;
                            c.gridwidth = 1;
                        input.add(newn, i);
                        }
                }
            illit++;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}   
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    System.out.println (aa);
}
}
class ImageLabel extends JLabel {
public ImageLabel (String img){
    this (new ImageIcon (img));
}
public ImageLabel (ImageIcon icon){
    setIcon(icon);
    setIconTextGap(0);
    setBorder(null);
    setText(null);
    setSize(icon.getImage().getWidth(null),icon.getImage().getHeight(null));
}
}
```

Comment: A lot will come down to the layout manager you are using, but you might consider using something like [`JComponent#add(Component, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20int))

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to add that, I am using a simple GridLayout, but I considered changing it to GridBag to specify specific placements. I decided against it because the tosses are based on a random number generator, so there's no surefire way to tell where I'd have to assign the icon.

Comment: `GridBagLayout` would allow you to define the grid cell, `GridLayout` you'll have to rely on the position of the component within the container

Comment: Okay, I'll make the switch over to a GridBagLayout then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container has a method getComponents(). JPanel is a descendant and will hopefully have it. To check for a given component you do the following:

```
Component[] cmp=myPanel.getComponents();
for(int i=0; i<cmp.length; i++)
  if(myComponent.equals(cmp[i])) {
    myPanel.remove(myComponent);
    myPanel.add(myNewComponent, i);
  }
```

where myComponent is the component you want to remove and myNewComponent is the component you want to add.

--

Ok your code uses some ColorPanel which I'm not familiar with but lets suppose its something like a JLabel.

I understand that you actually add (in the full code) as many colorpanels as coins in the image.

GridBag is out of my consideration - but maybe you should just skip the ipadx etc and just remove/add. Better yet use some /normal/ layout such as GridLayout or even FlowLayout for testing purposes.

Suggestion: have a JPanel (input) with a GridLayout(5, 5) where you add only the color panels (numbers). Have another JPanel (jp2) where you add the previous JPanel (input) and the button(confirm) - this jp2 is added to the jframe. You should add/remove on the input.

```
for(i=0; i<25; i++) input.add(new ColorPanel(...));


      thrown = pitch.nextInt(25);
            System.out.println(thrown);

      place=illit;
      spot.put(place, rSet);
      input.remove(thrown);
      Component newn = input.getComponent(place);
      input.add(newn, thrown);
```

Also make sure you call validate after each removal/addition:

```
input.validate();
```

In summary, the following is a simplified working program of what you are trying to do:

```
class T extends Frame {
  public T() {
    setSize(500, 500);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
    for(int i=0; i<25; i++) add(new Label(""+i));
    setVisible(true);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    T t=new T();
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      int r=(int)(Math.random()*25);
      t.remove(r);
      t.add(new Label(""+(i+1)), r);
      t.validate();
      t.repaint();
      try { Thread.sleep(5000); } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll update with pictures but it still fails to set it back into the empty spot.

Comment: maybe you can update with (full) code because we dont know what happens

Comment: Sorry it was taking me awhile to trim it down; I just updated it with a simplified section of the program since the original is almost 500 lines that nobody's going to want to comb through.